# import specific file formats from folder into Illustrator via script

Tags: javascript, import, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I have found this script online which is almost what I am looking for, but it needs to be adapted and I can't seem to get it to work.

```
    if (selectedFolder) {
        myDocument = app.documents.add();

        var firstImageLayer = true;
        var newLayer ;
        var thisPlacedItem;

        // create document list from files in selected folder
        var imageList = selectedFolder.getFiles();

        for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
            // open each document in file list
            if (imageList[i] instanceof File) {
                // get the file name
                var fName = imageList[i].name.toLowerCase();
                // check for supported file formats
                //if( (fName.indexOf(".eps") == -1) ) {
                if( (fName.indexOf(".tga") == -1) && (fName.indexOf(".png") == -1)) {
                    // skip unsupported formats
                    continue;
                } else {
                    if( firstImageLayer ) {
                        newLayer = myDocument.layers[0];
                        firstImageLayer = false;
                    } else {
                        newLayer = myDocument.layers.add();
                    }
                   // Give the layer the name of the image file
                   newLayer.name = fName.substring(0, fName.indexOf(".") );

                   // Place the image on the artboard
                   thisPlacedItem = newLayer.placedItems.add()
                   thisPlacedItem.file = imageList[i];

                   switch( placement9pointAlignment ) {
                        default :
                            break;
                        case "ul" : 
                            thisPlacedItem.top = myDocument.height;
                            thisPlacedItem.left = 0;
                            break;
                        case "ml" : 
                            thisPlacedItem.top = myDocument.height / 2 + thisPlacedItem.height / 2;
                            thisPlacedItem.left = 0;
                            break;
                        case "ll" : 
                            thisPlacedItem.top = thisPlacedItem.height;
                            thisPlacedItem.left = 0;
                            break;
                        case "ur" : 
                            thisPlacedItem.top = myDocument.height;
                            thisPlacedItem.left = myDocument.width - thisPlacedItem.width;
                            break;
                        case "mr" : 
                            thisPlacedItem.top = myDocument.height / 2 + thisPlacedItem.height / 2;
                            thisPlacedItem.left = myDocument.width - thisPlacedItem.width;
                            break;
                        case "lr" : 
                            thisPlacedItem.top = thisPlacedItem.height;
                            thisPlacedItem.left = myDocument.width - thisPlacedItem.width;
                            break;
                        case "um" : 
                            thisPlacedItem.top = myDocument.height;
                            thisPlacedItem.left = myDocument.width / 2 - thisPlacedItem.width / 2;
                            break;
                        case "mm" : 
                            thisPlacedItem.top = myDocument.height / 2 + thisPlacedItem.height / 2;
                            thisPlacedItem.left = myDocument.width / 2 - thisPlacedItem.width / 2;
                            break;
                        case "lm" : 
                            thisPlacedItem.top = thisPlacedItem.height;
                            thisPlacedItem.left = myDocument.width / 2 - thisPlacedItem.width / 2;
                            break;
                   }
                }
            }
        }

        if( firstImageLayer ) {
            // alert("The action has been cancelled.");
            // display error message if no supported documents were found in the designated folder
            alert("Sorry, but the designated folder does not contain any recognized image formats.\n\nPlease choose another folder.");
            myDocument.close();
            importFolderAsLayers(getFolder());
        }

    } else {
        // alert("The action has been cancelled.");
        // display error message if no supported documents were found in the designated folder
        alert("Rerun the script and choose a folder with images.");
        //importFolderAsLayers(getFolder());
    }
}

//Start the script off
importFolderAsLayers( getFolder() );
```

I want to be able to select a folder and have it only import .tga or .png files. if there are other file formats present, I want it to ignore them.

the problem with this script is that it is searching via filename, not via extension.
Ordinarily this would work fine, but I often receive .tga files along with a jpeg copy named image_01.tga.jpeg

This is a problem because now when I use the script it imports the tga and the jpeg!

Does anyone know how I could adapt this script so it searches specifically by extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`getFiles()`](https://javascript-tools-guide.readthedocs.io/file-system-access/folder-object.html?highlight=getFiles#getfiles) method that you're utilizing in the line that reads;

> ```js
> var imageList = selectedFolder.getFiles();
> ```

accepts a `mask` argument - it's essentially a RegExp pattern.

If you change that line to;

```
var imageList = selectedFolder.getFiles(/\.(tga|png)$/i);
```

it will ensure that the list of files assigned to the `imageList` variable are only files that end in `.tga`, `.TGA`, `.png`, or `.PNG`.

Then you don't have to do any filtering of file types in the `for` loop.